# How do you change update frequency of a ClickOnce application?

Tags: clickonce

I have the update frequency of my ClickOnce application set to weekly.  What is the effect of changing the frequency before I publish a new version?

Will it take effect next time client hits weekly check date?  Can it be forced to update earlier (say an emergency upgrade due to security issue)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will have any effect unless you publish a new version, and the installed version hits a check date and updates.

I think if you require a certain version number you can specify it in the "Specify a minimum required version section". But this will not change the frequency. If you foresee needing a certain version and the installed apps have good bandwidth to the deployment location, choosing "Before the Application Starts" as the update method may be better.

This article is useful for clickonce update strategy:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e%28VS.80%29.aspx